# Return 404 page when someone access any .php?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I always hide the files *.php* extension in .htaccess. However, if anyone access the *.php* file returns a unexpected error page that should be 404 page in the current *.htaccess* text.

My actual text (from @anubhava answer):

```
# to present a custom 404 page
ErrorDocument 404 ./error

RewriteEngine On

# return 404 for direct .php requests
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \.php[/\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [R=404,L]

# silent rewrite to add .php extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Just a test. **Edit**: I believe the error is on the 404 document, as the 404 error is being returned now. Instead of appear the 404 page, it appears the directory I input in my browser page, as below:

> ./error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a rule you place just below `RewriteEngine On` to present 404 for the requests for `.php` files:

```
# to present a custom 404 page
ErrorDocument 404 /error

RewriteEngine On

# return 404 for direct .php requests
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \.php[/\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule !^error - [R=404,L]

# silent rewrite to add .php extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Great answer! But why when I access a file without the ".php" extension I give the 404 page?

Comment: You need an internal rewrite to `.php` rule and I thought you wrote in question it is already working for you. If not I will add that rule also.

Comment: After monthies I still didn't get to return the such 404 page. Few monthies ago I was searching what could be the problem, but nothing looks to solve my problem, neither the non-duplicate question answer works for me. I'm doing this as a test in localhost and the files are short, just having a text like "Test !". `.htaccess` is the any action file here yet. I'll post the `.htaccess` text in my question...

Comment: I think the 404 page isn't being succesfully redirected now. Your text works in this case now.

Comment: After trying, I received the error `Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.`, probably for my configuration :( . Anyway, the text works as expected, not the 404 page.

Comment: This was tested on my Apache. Does `http://domain.com/error` URL work for you?

Comment: Yes. The error page works, less when it's returned as the 404 page error. The return page is currently from Apache now, with the error I did quote in the comment. ;|

Comment: Does your `error.php` exist in `DocumentRoot`? Also did you note `RewriteRule !^error - [R=404,L]` in my answer?